# How to run Job Scheduler daily in the evening

Tags: android, android-layout, alarmmanager, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I want to run my job using Job Scheduler daily. I already looked at setPeriodic(long intervalMillis) but don't know how to use it to run the job daily in evening around 7:00PM (although not exact 7:00)

```
  public  void scheduleJob(View view){
    ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),MJobService.class.getName());
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceName);
    builder.setPersisted(true);

    JobInfo myJobInfo = builder.build();
    mScheduler.schedule(myJobInfo);


}
```

Comment: Use AlarmManager instead of JobScheduler

Answer (score 1):

`JobScheduler` is specifically designed for inexact timing. Your best option will be `AlarmManager`. Try like below:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, alarmIntent);
```

Implement your logic inside `AlarmReceiver`.

Comment: I dont need exact timing, but it should be around 7:00 PM, I used this because I read that on reboot Alarmmanger will not work.

Comment: There is nothing about **around**. Either at exact time or anytime within 24 hours. To solve boot problem you can use `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/> ` in `AndroidManifest` with BroadcastReceiver

Comment: thank you! One more thing, can we use WorkManager instead of AlarmManager here.

Comment: No, actually `WorkManager` internally use `JobScheduler`. For exact time scheduling AlarmManager is recommended. Hope this help you. Please accept the answer and hit upvote as usual. Thanks

Comment: @user6299305, if it will help you then accept the answer and hit upvote so that others can find it helpful. Thanks

Comment: Done, I need one more help. In some phones like one plus I think  due to battery optimisation alarm manager not working. Will using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() solve this problem, or I need whitelist or take permission   for the app to bypass battery optimisation

Comment: @user6299305, Any problem? Why you reverse?